# Issue generating XML and probably other formats in Laravel API call, Invalid Character

Tags: json, xml, laravel, character-encoding, char

I am using a Laravel API route handler to serve data with a JSON or XML response instead of .tsv or .csv. However, I am getting an "Invalid Character Error" when I try to create an element using the line of code below:

```php
$node = $dom->createElement($key, $value);
```

I also tried using the Spatie library with no success. I have verified that my `database.php` configuration and other Laravel app settings are correct and that the encoding of the database is:

```php
DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci
```

In addition, the `.env` file has the following relevant section:

```
DB_CHARSET=utf8mb4
DB_COLLATION=utf8mb4_unicode_ci
```

When I tried to debug, I discovered that the response data is encoded as ASCII:

```
Value: needs mapping
Encoding: ASCII
Is ASCII: Yes
```

That is from a debug echo prior to encoding to XML.

Kind of scratching my head about why that might be, and how to resolve it.  I haven't tried escaping it, but the data itself is pretty clean I think, except for maybe some single or double quotes here and there and '&', likely not HTML.

I suspect this to be the issue when creating the element. I have tried using `htmlentities` to convert the data, but I still receive the "Invalid Character Error." Can someone help me resolve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

I think I may have figured it out, but still not clear why it is telling me that the encoding is ACSII.

The Tag Names that were provided for a couple of the tags were not adherent to the standard, thus it could not encode the XML string.